# Accessing properties of a project using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, biztalk, envdte

I'm writing a visual studio add-in to automate some of our BizTalk related tasks.

I'd like to be able to access the property values of a project (not what shows in the default 'Properties' pane. The properties shown in a window if you right click on the project and select 'properties' from the context menu.)

Specifically I'd like to get/set the application it deploys to, assembly signing, etc. The rest of the add-in is already working.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a statement of your goals.  What have you done to achieve them? Why is this not working?

Comment: I don't know where to find the information I need to accomplish my goals. Further, specifying goals allows potential responses that may suggest an alternative approach which is superior or a clarification of my understanding of the approach. It seems a trivial enough improvement I'm surprised stack overflow readers don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it includes deploys/assembly signing and it's hard to give a complete sample as there is lots of supporting code, but you can start from [IVsSolutionBuildManager.FindActiveProjectCfg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager.findactiveprojectcfg.aspx), cast the result to IVsProjectCfg2 and enumerate OutputGroups.

Comment: Thank you, a pointer in the right direction helps. All my pointers were null ;)